# How to add all subdirectories in "Include directories" in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, github

When cloning a repo on github, I have made with lots of subfolders (like src, include and then several sub-directories in those) on a new PC. But I get a heap of errors that it can't find the paths for the include files. How do I quickly let Visual Studio know to look for include files in those sub-directories and not just the main folder where I cloned the repo?

Going into properties and choosing "include directories" I can manually select paths to look for include files, but I obviously don't want to manually add the dozens of sub-folders where include files can be found. Preferably I would like whoever is cloning the repo to not have to worry about this at all of course if there is something to do about this when creating the repo. Thank you!

The github repo for reference: https://github.com/OscarUngsgard/Cpp-Monte-Carlo-Value-at-Risk-Engine

And a picture of the "include directories" options I'm referring to in Visual Studio:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there's no way to search for include files in subfolders. And it's obvious if this was possible it would not be relevant to do that as this will take more time to search them.

But you can do one thing, when including files just add their relative path
Such as

```
#include "../src/header_file.h"
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. Would that be considered best practice or standard, or something that is commonly done? I think that would work and might even look a bit neat but it would be an hour of monotonous grueling work clearly so it's not something I just want to throw myself onto

Comment: yes that's tedious task. But  there's just these two ways. You include the path in code itself or just add each directory

Comment: most programmers keep all header files in one place for easy including or otherwise using the above mentioned

Comment: if you are familiar with java, there's the packages we have to include, its more like adding the path

Comment: I see, that is good to know. So you only would do ´#include "../include/header_file.h"´ for all the files then, which is simple enough. I was told to create subfolders for my files to group them together based on functionality, but perhaps that is usually only done for the src files and not the header files?

Comment: I won't say that you cant do. but what you were doing was about header files and they lie under special include folder in same directory

Comment: Hey would I be able to trouble you a bit more? I tried changing all my code to do "../include/header_file.h"´ and it works for the files that are directly in the src directory but for the files in subdirectories like \src\subdirectory\file.cpp it doesn't work. How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you added the complete path like \src\subdirectory\file.cpp ?

Comment: You need to add relative path with your base file.Ideally you should use forward slashes in paths too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216252/discussion-between-nikhil-ghule-and-oscar).